# golang check if javascript is enabled

Tags: go

this is my actual code :

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

const BaseUrl = "http://127.0.01:5000"
const ListeningPort = "80"

func main() {
    // intercept call
    http.HandleFunc("/test", Test)

    // all other traffic pass on
    http.HandleFunc("/", ProxyFunc)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+ListeningPort, nil)
}

func ProxyFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    u, err := url.Parse(BaseUrl)
    if err != nil {
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u)
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func Test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("TEST"))
}
```

first to accept client connexion, i want to check if browser have enabled javascript, how i can do this in my actual code ?

i want check with this method :
https://pastebin.com/ZASFQumf

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that in Golang since it is a server side language. I don't even think it is possible with JavaScript.

It is not something you can add/set/get from the headers.

What you are trying to do is check browser specific flags.

You might be able to find third party libraries used to manage Chrome flags or Firefox flags etc. That is your best option.